# ESQL produces incorrect syntax near timestamp

Tags: sql-server, exception, odbc, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

ESQL compute node of production IBM WebSphere integration bus contains the following ESQL query:

```
SET result[] =
  SELECT p.Id, p.Date, p.Value
  FROM   DatabaseName.dbo.TableName AS p
  WHERE  p.Date >= InputRoot.XMLNSC.ns:RequestType.Request.DateFrom
  AND    p.Date <= InputRoot.XMLNSC.ns:RequestType.Request.DateTo;
```

`DateFrom` and `DateTo` are described in XSD as `xsd:dateTime`, and therefore are treated as `TIMESTAMP`.
Integration bus produces the following query:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Date, p.Value 
FROM DatabaseName.dbo.TableName as p 
WHERE p.Date < TIMESTAMP'2016-01-02 00:00:00' and p.Date >= TIMESTAMP'2016-01-01'
```

which is incorrect and results in exception

> [IBM][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver][Microsoft SQL Server]
>   Incorrect syntax near '2016-09-29 00:00:00'

What is much more strange, test IBM WebSphere works good and does not generate this weird "TIMESTAMP" prefix, while production integration bus is a full clone of test integration bus virtual machine.

SQL Server versions of both test and production remote database and its compatibility levels are the same (SQL Server 2008 R2; 80).

**Exception details**:

> Catalog = 'BIPmsgs'
>   Number = 2322
>   Text = Child SQL exception
>   File = '/build/S1000_slot1/S1000_P/src/DataFlowEngine/MessageServices/ImbOdbc.cpp'
>   Line = 3776
>   Function = 'ImbOdbcStatement::checkRcInner'
>
> SQL State = HY000
>   Native Error Code = 102
>   Error Text = [IBM][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver][Microsoft SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '2016-09-29 00:00:00'.

Comment: Can you clarify which database is having the problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Both test and production servers are SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the obvious workaround - I have converted TIMESTAMP to a string myself, and passed a string to ESQL:

```
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.DateFromString = 
   CAST(requestNode.DateFrom AS CHARACTER FORMAT 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS');
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.DateToString = 
   CAST(requestNode.DateTo AS CHARACTER FORMAT 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS');

SET result[] =
  SELECT p.Id, p.Date, p.Value
  FROM   DatabaseName.dbo.TableName AS p
  WHERE  p.Date >= OutputLocalEnvironment.DateFromString
  AND    p.Date <= OutputLocalEnvironment.DateToString;
```

It produces a correct query, but doesn't solve the problem and doesn't explain why it works on test, but does not on production.
The question is open.